# Whenever I create a new button my app force closes

Tags: android, layout, button, dynamic, view

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class register_activity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.register, null);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        Button btnCreateNew = new Button(this);
        btnCreateNew.setText("Create New User");
        btnCreateNew.offsetTopAndBottom(10);
        btnCreateNew.offsetLeftAndRight(10);
        RLayout.addView(btnCreateNew, p);

    }
}
```

So that code works and runs just fine, only I can not see the button being displayed. The layout is simply blank with nothing inside it.

What is wrong?

Comment: Add the error you are getting from the logcat

Comment: ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.npaxton.assaulttd/com.npaxton.assaulttd.register_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a NullPointerException, right? (Check your LogCat!)

The reason:

1. You create a Button as a member variable with `this` as a parameter. That might cause some trouble as `this` might not be defined when `new Button(this)` is called. Move the initialization into `onCreate`
2. Your `RLayout` will be null, and here I am very sure. The reason is, that you can't call `findViewById()` before you called `setContentView()`. If you call it before, Android has no idea where to look at and returns null.

*update*

As you changed your question quite a bit, here is my updated answer:

You set your content to `R.layout.register` and after that you inflate it again.

My solution for you: just use `setContentView(R.layout.register)`, than use `findViewById(R.id.layout_id)` and finally create and add your button:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    Button btnCreateNew = new Button(this);
    btnCreateNew.setText("Create New User");
    btnCreateNew.offsetTopAndBottom(10);
    btnCreateNew.offsetLeftAndRight(10);
    RLayout.addView(btnCreateNew, p);
}
```

Of course you can also add the button in the xml layout directly. I would prefer this way, because you have a better separation between layout and code.

Basic XML structure (style it to as you want):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/button_text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The reason for you blank screen was, that you added the button to the new created `RLayout` but this layout was never part of your screen (never added by `setContentView()`)

Comment: very nice, let me try this, and i have posted in the comments the logcat twice :p lol

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        
        RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.register);
        Button btnCreateNew = new Button(this);
        btnCreateNew.setText("Create New");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
  RLayout.addView(btnCreateNew, p);
        
    }
}

Comment: So i removed all the lines that dealt with the button, and left all the layout stuff and it worked. so it works without the button being included.

Comment: could you please update the new code in your question? as a comment it isn't readable. Also highlight the line that causes the error and please add the complete stack trace (error) to your question...

Comment: Ok thankyou I did as requested, and updated the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try rearranging your lines of codes. In the main class change `Button btnCreateNew = new Button(this);` into `Button btnCreateNew;` Or just move the whole line into `onCreate()`. What does your error say in your logcat?

Comment: I tried that it didn't help. The logcat says 12-26 19:17:58.235: E/AndroidRuntime(220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.npaxton.assaulttd/com.npaxton.assaulttd.register_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `this` and `getApplicationContext()` try changing this into `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Button btnCreateNew = new Button(getApplicationContext());

I tried with that as well and same thing still.

Comment: getApplicationContext() only needs to be used when you are going to keep a reference to the Context after an Activity exits or for some other long period of time. if you are keeping it only for the lifetime of the Activity, hence, we are using a Button, you should *not* use getApplicationContext(). This is documented "This generally should only be used if you need a Context whose lifecycle is separate from the current context," http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()

Comment: OP's problem is that he tried to initialize a Button using the state of the current Context before it was initialized. He should have created the Button in onCreate(). As you probably know, Activity inherits from Context.

Comment: So OP forgot to set the content view, totally overlooked that.. good eyes. I've never seen that issue because I always configure my layouts properly. Also thanks for the insight into context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class register_activity extends Activity {

Button btnCreateNew;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
btnCreateNew = new Button(R.layout.register);
}
```

This should work. Your not pointing to which xml the button should be extracted from.

Comment: the code gets underlined and it asks me to switch the context of r.layout.register

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class register_activity extends Activity {
Button btnCreateNew;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.register, null);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        btnCreateNew = new Button(this);
        btnCreateNew.setText("Create New User");
        btnCreateNew.offsetTopAndBottom(10);
        btnCreateNew.offsetLeftAndRight(10);
        RLayout.addView(btnCreateNew, p);
        setContentView(RLayout);
    }
}
```

In the end all I had to do was re set the `contentView`; I figured it had to be some sort of view update.

*Awesome*! Thank you everyone :)

Comment: Ah, just saw your answer :) I updated my answer, too. Also: `setContentView()` should be called only once. If you use it as you wrote, you should simply remove the first call.